# OutOfMemoryError - layer-list image background

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap, layer-list

My background image is a PNG 375 × 667
Note that i'm **NOT** using `setContentView()` in my activity's `onCreate()`
I'm purely making use of a theme
Using a normal activity layout, user will see a blank dark screen for 2-3 seconds before they can see the Splash screen image the 1st time they launch the app ==> **not** what I want
I need the Splash screen image to show up immediately when user opens the app
Some people make the Splash screen transparent which means user will see nothing happens for 2-3 seconds the first time ==> **unacceptable** for me

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name=".views.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
    </style>
```

**bg_splash.xml**

```
<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/splash_full_tiny"
    android:gravity="center">
</item>
```

This only happens a few devices:

- Vodafone Smart ultra 6
- A1601 (Oppo)
- SM-A800I (Samsung)

Comment: I think your are calling  delay of 3 seconds ,  can you check in your java code?

Comment: maybe try <item><bitmap android:drawable="@drawable/splash_full_tiny" android:gravity="center"></bitmap>
</item> and see if that could help.

Answer (score 0):

try add this android:largeHeap="true"

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        ></application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply your SplashTheme style in application tag or you can add background to appTheme same as splashtheme. This will show your splash image quickly. Make sure once implemented check all activities. because it will used as background in your application. In all activities which have transparent background it will shows it as backgroud. I hope this may help you.

Answer (score -1):

For this you should use different Images for different devices or any small image.

Comment: Please read my question carefully to understand why I did go for your approach